# SQL + .NET "Could not find stored procedure", SP will be deleted after program start

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures, windows-services

I have a following problem:

I've written a win service program transfering data from one source (OPC) to SQL database.
In database I have created 3 stored procedures (all data will be separated on 3 tables).

After start of service one SP will be lost - somehow deleted, and then I get "Could not find stored procedure".

If I create this SP during service is running - everything works fine, but after restart it will be deleted again.

All 3 calls of SP are identical:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(SQL_CONNSTRING))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.SP_name", myConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Line", SqlDbType.Int, 1).Value = line;
            object idr = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

The SP deletion happens approximately by `ExecuteScalar()`

Can anybody explain me why it happens and how can I avoid it?

I have searched something about it, but search on "SP could not be found" brings me only the situations where SP is presenrt. My will be deleted and thatswhy not found.

**upd:** similar situation described, w/o solution: http://www.sql-questions.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services/31612416/stored-procedure-getting-deleted.aspx

**UPD2:** solved

My fault - the SP was deleted from another SP.

Trace helped me to find the moment it happens on [Thanks to **dash** - *read comments below the question*], and so the SP in which it happens.

Somehow this second SP contained the first rows of script for creation my needed SP.

Because this second SP is called very rarely but for sure once at start - everything seems ok after recreation.

Sorry for such stupid question and thanks to all who tried to help me! :)

Comment: I think you're the only responsible for SP deletion!

Comment: yeah, but how? where? in code there is nothing what can delete SP or?

Comment: and why only one of three SP's will be deleted?

Comment: Try not to prefix stored procs with "sp_" - see http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/. Regards your issue, how are your stored procedures declared? Are you prefixing them with a username? Do you have a DROP statement in there anywhere? It can't be an accident that it happens when you EXECUTE the stored proc.

Comment: 1. SP name is without "sp_" - it's only example here, bad example sorry
2. sp is prefixed with dbo, as i understand it's username.
3. in SP intern there are no drop, just INSERT.
4. if i call SP direct in ssms - everything is good, AND as i wrote - if I create SP during service is running - everything is good too

Comment: I mean; if you script the stored procedure, is there a drop statement in the create script - sometimes a missing "GO" statement can lead to funny behaviour. One thing you can do is run a trace on your sql box and look for the "object dropped" event. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx or http://serverfault.com/questions/69056/how-to-find-when-the-stored-procedure-was-deleted-and-who-deleted-it Other possibilities include the fact that it is still there but you don't have permission to see it in the object browser.

Comment: yeah, it was script:

IF EXISTS (...) and type in ('P', 'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Save_Counter]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Save_Counter]
 @param1 int,...

As I understand - GO is tehere.
And thank you, I'll read your links

Answer (score 0):

- or your user has no permission to run the SP
- or it is an intended behavior of SP code - probably it deletes itself (if this possible)
- or **sp_** prefix makes your server look for the procedure in **master** db and you have some interferences then